# Manipulating more than 1 object from a class?

Tags: java, arrays, function, class, methods

I'm making a bingo program which required me to make a class which made the bingo card in the form of a 2D array.
I then checked how many times a user has to call in order for that card in play to achieve bingo.
Right now I'm kinda confused as to how to do the next part of the question which is to have 500 of those bingo cards in play at the same time and to calculate how long it would take to just have 1 of those 500 cards to be bingo.
I don't understand how I can create 500 instances of the same class at the same time and to operate a method on all of them a the same time

Comment: [Check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: By placing the cards in an array or List, and using loops.

Comment: Short: you can't, you need to iterate over the instances you have and make a call on each on them. (as JB Nizet already stated).